# Stop and Start AWS Fargate App (Task) based upon usage for cost saving?

Tags: aws-fargate

Before you mark this question duplicate, I know there have been some questions asked about how to programmatically stop AWS Fargate Tasks when there are some technical issue with the task but my question is a little different.

I want to start and stop AWS Fargate Task based upon usage to save cost, i.e. when there is no traffic to the app, the ECS stops the Task and when there is some user accessing the app, the ECS starts the task. This will be helpful given that Fargate is pay-for-what-you-use kind of service.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really possible because you will lose all responses that come in during the time the Fargate task is down, until the time the task starts up and is ready to accept connections. There is nowhere to "save" or "store" those requests while the container is starting.

However AWS does have another service that is similar to ECS/Fargate that does support placing a container into a "sleep" state to reduce costs when there are no incoming requests. That service is [AWS App Runner](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apprunner/latest/dg/what-is-apprunner.html).